# how to stop npm start and npm run dev to start my project, I want yarn to only start my project and run dev

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, yarn-workspaces

(i want yarn start and yarn run dev will work not npm will work it will show error to use yarn)

This is my script in package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "if [ \"$npm_config_user_agent\" != \"yarn\" ]; then echo \"Error: Use 'yarn start' to run this application\" && exit 1; fi",
    "start": "yarn run dev",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
```

This script stoping me to run yarn start and npm start, i want to only npm start to not run.

Comment: CTRL+C  that stop npm start and run dev

Comment: I think ctrl+c is not what he wanted he want to force the dev to use the yarn instead if npm

Comment: yes i want to force the dev to use the yarn instead if npm

Answer (score 0):

Hi to force use of yarn instead of npm , create .npmrc file in root
add this in it

```
 engine-strict = true
```

and in package.josn
add this

```
"engines": {
    "npm": "Use-yarn",
    "yarn": ">= 1.19.1"
  },
```

Above , the package.json file uses a valid version of yarn.
But for npm we specify an invalid version.

this will force user to install modules using yarn and if you want to disable the npm start you can add this in package json

```
"prestart": "node -e \"if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('You must use Yarn to start, not NPM')\"",
```

Script will look like this :

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "node -e \"if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('You must use Yarn to install, not NPM')\"",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Hope this helps

Comment: "prestart": "echo \"npm_execpath=$npm_execpath\" && test $npm_execpath = \"yarn.js\" || (echo \"Error: Use 'yarn start' to run this application\" && exit 1)", then what this mean can you please explain me?

Comment: rm -rf the lock file and node-modules , do fresh yarn install and yarn start

Comment: the above method is not working\

Comment: can you tell me the error you getting

Comment: it is not enforcing to use yarn. npm start is also working

Comment: I dont think there is a way at least not an official way to enforce that

Comment: "scripts": {
    "prestart": "if [ \"$npm_config_user_agent\" != \"yarn\" ]; then echo \"Error: Use 'yarn start' to run this application\" && exit 1; fi",
    "start": "yarn run dev",
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  }, this script stoping me to use both yarn start and npm start

Comment: try this 

    "prestart": "node -e \"if(process.env.npm_execpath.indexOf('yarn') === -1) throw new Error('You must use Yarn to start, not NPM')\"",

Comment: check the modified answer @Pankaj Shah

Comment: now yarn start is working and npm start is not working, but i also want to stop npm run dev and i want yarn run dev to run and what is issue in

Comment: "prestart": "if [ \"$npm_config_user_agent\" != \"yarn\" ]; then echo \"Error: Use 'yarn start' to run this application\" && exit 1; fi",

Comment: not sure how to stop that but if you add     "dev": "yarn react-scripts start",  it will run yarn run dev ,even if you use npm run dev

Comment: "prestart": "if [ \"$npm_config_user_agent\" != \"yarn\" ]; then echo \"Error: Use 'yarn start' to run this application\" && exit 1; fi",     why this prestart not work?